# Value of $a,b $ given two conditions

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If the function $f (x)=a\log|x|+bx^2+x $ has extreme points at $x=-1,2$ then the value of $a,b $ is? Now at extreme points $1^{st}$ derivative is $0$ so I differentiated it by making cases :

i.e.  $x <0,x>0$(which is probably wrong) so we get two equations as $0.5a-4b=-1,2a-4b=-2$:but they yield a wrong answer. Wheres the fault?Thanks

Comment: Now, what _was_ the correct answer?

Comment: $a=2,b-0.5$ is the answer given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$
f'(x)=\frac{a}x+2bx+1,\quad x\neq0,
$$ then
$$
f'(-1)=0 \implies -a-2b+1=0,\quad f'(2)=0 \implies \frac{a}2+4b+1=0
$$ giving
$$
a+2b=1,\quad a+8b=-2
$$ and one finds 
$$
a=2,\quad b=-\frac12.
$$

Comment: It should be 2 .